# date function to calculate only week days

Tags: javascript

requirement is one  text box which contains current date that date should show current date +  next five days which should calculate only week days(monday to friday) and wants to display in text box
 anybody send me this code
 plz let me know if any description

Comment: What do you mean by `that date should show current date + next five days`, is there one single day or multiple boxes with separate dates?

Comment: The people on StackOverflow are very willing to *help* you come up with solutions to your programming problems. This question looks more like you're asking someone to write it for you, which tends to put people off. (It's also not clear exactly what you're asking for it to do.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you're looking to do, but these things should help:

1. You can create `Date` objects for specific dates using the three-argument constructor function: `Date(year, month, date)` where `year` is the full year (e.g., 2011), `month` is the month number (`0` = January), and `date` is the day of the month (1-28/29/30/31 depending). E.g.:

   ```
   var dt = new Date(2011, 0, 31); // January 31st, 2011
   ```
2. You can tell what day of the *week* a given `Date` represents by using its `getDay` function; that returns a number with `0` = Sunday, `1` = Monday, etc.:

   ```
   var day = dt.getDay();
   if (day == 6/*Saturday*/ || day == 0/*Sunday*/) {
       // It's Saturday or Sunday
   }
   else {
       // It isn't, it's a weekday
   }
   ```
3. You can advance a `Date` instance to the next day like so:

   ```
   dt = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 1);
   ```

   The `Date` constructor will handle wrapping to the next month (and possibly year) for you.
4. You can set the value of a text field by assigning to the `value` property of the DOM element for the field. You can get the DOM element any of several ways. One way is to give the element an `id` attribute (which must be unique) and then use

   ```
   var element = document.getElementById("idstring");
   ```

   ...to look it up.
5. You'll obviously need a loop to build up your list of five weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve part of your problem, at least on how to add x days to a Date and skip the weekends...

```
Date.prototype.addWeekDays = function(days)
    {
        var d = this;
        var dow = d.getUTCDay();

        var daysToAdd = (dow + days < 6) ? days : days + 2;

       return new Date(
        d.getUTCFullYear(), 
        d.getUTCMonth(), 
        d.getUTCDate() + daysToAdd, 
        d.getUTCHours(), 
        d.getUTCMinutes(), 
        d.getUTCSeconds(), 
        d.getUTCMilliseconds());
     };
```

Example: var d = new Date("5 Feb 2011").addWeekDays(1); //This should return 1 (Monday)